# Line repeat in processing with python

Tags: python, loops, processing, repeat, lines

i wanna loop a line function in processing using python. it works but without any motion. i wanna loop line like this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KUg9dcIFtM 
but in python this not work. it is static.
This is my code:

```
def setup():
    size(400,600);
    background(255);
     def draw():
    x=0;
    num=600;
    andx=0;
    for x in range(0,600,20):
        line(x,0,x,600);
        x+=20;
        andx+=20;
        if andx>400:
            andx=0;
```

why i have no motion?
[screen of the sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfDbg.png)

Comment: `time.sleep(secs)` maybe is what you want? The problem is a bit unclear, from the screenshot i see that you get the correct output

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yeah, i know it is the correct output but if u see the video i linked u see the loop in motion of lines... i wanna that motion.

Comment: All you have is a `setup` function, but no `draw`. By definition, the setup code is only run once. Why did you expect otherwise? Note that a loop doesn't create a different frame for each iteration. It is `draw` that draws frames.

Comment: because i'm looking for an animation everytime a new line is created by the loop. i don't want all the lines at the same time on the output, but a line once a second for example.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KUg9dcIFtM this video explain what i'm looking for. but this is processing with java. i'm working with processing in python

Comment: Have your setup draw nothing. Have your draw draw a single line. Maybe read a tutorial, since it seems as if you haven't yet wrapped your mind around the basic flow of a sketch ( which is the same in both Java and Python).

Comment: i read lots of tutorial and i don't know why lines are not animating while repeating like the video i linked. if i transpose the same code of the video from java to python lines are not animating, just the output is static and i want animation

Comment: so if i wanna do the same thing of the video what i have to do in python processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to follow that video I can see how it was somewhat confusing (given all of the commented out code). A working Python equivalent is:

```
andx = 0 #global variable to determine placement of final line

def setup():
    size(400,600)
    frameRate(5)

def draw():
    global andx
    background("#EC4DF5")
    stroke(50)
    for x in xrange(0,andx,20):
        line(x,0,x,height)
    andx += 20
    if andx > width:
        andx = 0
```

`draw()` is what actually draws in an animation loop. Any drawing function such as `line()` is *buffered* with the display only redrawn at the end of the call to `draw()`.

For tutorials, it would be better to see the Python-based ones [here](http://py.processing.org/) rather than Java ones on YouTube.